# Genymotion error at start 'Unable to load virtualbox'

Tags: windows, virtualbox, genymotion

I've installed the genymotion+virtualbox package on Windows 7 64-bit and everything goes fine... But when I start Genymotion it presents me an error message `Unable to load virtualbox`.

VirtualBox is installed and I'm able to start it manually. I've tried to install the packages separately, updated virtualbox to 4.2.16 but nothing worked.

I've already read genymotion FAQ but it did not help.

Comment: Randomly got this issue the other week after Geny worked fine for a couple months. Reinstalling VirtualBox is what resolved it for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Linux at least, I had to restart VirtualBox, running this command on terminal:

```
/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox restart
```

[Seems to be the same on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629013/genymotion-unable-to-load-virtualbox-engine-on-mavericks-vbox-is-setup-corr).

Comment: –1 OP specifically said he's using windows.

Answer (score 27):

I have spend all day to solve this error since none of the answers worked for me.

I found out that oracle virtual box doesn't install the **network adapter** correctly in windows 8.1

Solution:

1. Delete all previous virtual box adapters
2. Go to device manager and click "Action" > "Add legacy hardware"
3. Install the oracle virtual box adapters manually (my path was `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers\network\netadp\VBoxNetAdp.inf`)

Now that virtual box adapters is installed correctly, it needs to be setup correctly. (the following solution is like many other solution in here)

1. Start Oracle VM VirtualBox and go to "File" > "Preferences" > "Network" > "Host-only Network"
2. Click edit
3. Set IPv4 `192.168.56.1` mask `255.255.255.0`
4. Click DHCP Server tab and set server adr: `192.168.56.100` server Mask: `255.255.255.0` low address bound: `192.168.56.101` upper adress bound `192.168.56.254`
5. Now click OK and start genymotion

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my life. But I suggest a little modification, change the virtual adapter's IP via network connections because through VirtualBox it returns to default values every time you change them. Cheers!

Comment: wow thanks for this solution. Literally spent over a week trying to find a fix for this problem.

Comment: strangely this also worked for me.. using genymotion 2.11.0 and oracle virtual box 5.2.6 r120293, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Had the same problem, Uninstall Genymotion, install VirtualBox stand alone from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads then install the  Genymotion package without VirtualBox.

Comment: I closed Android Studio but it still didn't work at all. Then I uninstalled both Genymotion and VirtualBox. Reinstalling them resolved the problem. This error occurred after upgrading to Mavericks.

Answer (score 7):

Try closing Android Studio/Eclipse if it's open. It worked for me.

Comment: and run genymotion as administrator

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me in Windows 7 is to remove the Host-only Network (in Oracle virtual box **Preferences** menu [CTRL+G] -> **Network** -> **Host-only Networks**). Genymotion will recreate it automatically at the next virtual device start. For the record; I'm using a Nexus S 2.3.7 virtual device.

Answer (score 3):

Open Genymotion in Windows as an **administrator**. My Genymotion works only in this mode

Comment: at the same time, close android studio before launching genymotion

Answer (score 3):

### FIXED SOLUTION

Run below command in terminal, It denotes where is your virtualbox install on MAC/Linux.

```
    $ which vboxmanage
    /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage
```

Genymotion search the virtualBox in */usr/bin/VBoxManage* while it is located to */usr/local/bin/VBoxManage* ,  you need to create the symlink to that location , Run in terminal to fix it.

```
    sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage /usr/bin/VBoxManage
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using **Intellij IDEA** and same error happened to me, I found that the path to `genymotion` folder was not configured properly. Either open **settings** using `File > Settings` or press `Ctrl + Alt + S` then in `IDE Settings` check if the path to the `genymotion` folder is correct or not.

Since `Android Studio` are almost similar to `Intellij IDEA` so you can apply the same steps above to `Android Studio` as well.

[image: genymotion settings]

Answer (score 2):

Actually it seems like Genymotion has an issue with the newer versions of Virtual box, I had the same issue on my Mac but when I downgraded to 4.3.30 it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that GenyMotion is in your PATH environment variable.  I noticed mine was not auto populated, so once I entered it, it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows there are 2 installers. Did you use the bundle containing VirtualBox installer? 
It is call **Windows 32/64 bits (with VirtualBox)**.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask what this has to do with that , but by right clicking the genymotion application file and changing to compatibility to Vista solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this when I upgraded operating system from `Windows 8` to `Windows 8.1`. Un-installing `Virtualbox` and re-installing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close Android Studio (if Android Studio is running)
2. Run Genymotion as administrator

that's all! simple.

Answer (score -3):

try launching it via android-studio/eclipse plugin. Thats how I had similar issue when launching it from ubuntu.