# Genymotion unable to load VirtualBox engine

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtualbox, genymotion

I have installed genymotion (with virtual box) from this link.

https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/launchpad/download/

virtual box lunch successfully, but genimotion alerts message [image: genymotion errot]

[image: virtualbox]

Comment: The question is already answered in the following thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996901/genymotion-error-at-start-unable-to-load-virtualbox?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

genymotion site explain how to solve this error :)

> https://www.genymotion.com/faq/#windows-ten-start-impossible

```
Uninstall VirtualBox.
Reboot your computer if prompted by the installer.
Install the version of VirtualBox recommended for Windows 10
Reboot your computer if prompted by the installer.
Open VirtualBox and go to File > Preferences > Network.
Remove all existing host-only networks by clicking Description 1.
Start Genymotion a first time.
In the event of a failure, start Genymotion a second time.
```

If Genymotion still doesn’t run, you can manually configure a host-only network:

```
Open VirtualBox and go to File > Preferences > Network.
Add a new host-only network by clicking Description 1.
Edit its configuration by clicking Description 1.
In the Adapter tab, set the following values:
    IPv4 Address: 192.168.56.1
    IPv4 Network Mask: 255.255.255.0
In the DHCP Server tab, set the following values:
    Check Enable Server.
    Server Address: 192.168.56.100
    Server Mask: 255.255.255.0
    Lower Address Bound: 192.168.56.101
    Upper Address Bound: 192.168.56.254
```