# VirtualBox error when Genymotion

Tags: android, genymotion

I want use **Genymotion** for test android application, but when start device in **genymotion**, for example **Samsung S6 android 6.0** show me this error : 
[Error Image](http://uploads.im/41FYT.jpg)

**Update post :** my OS has : Windows 10

How can i fix VirtualBox error and run device?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996901/genymotion-error-at-start-unable-to-load-virtualbox

Comment: Happens to me all the time. You just have to open VirtualBox first. Then without closing it launch the genymotion.