# genymotion won't run with virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, fedora, genymotion

I installed virtual box properly but this problem persist.
i am using fedora 23.

[Unable to load VirtualBox engine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwP8g.png)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try restarting virtual box from the terminal or running Genymotion as an admin without an IDE open on startup.

Also, here are two other threads with similar problems:

[Genymotion error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996901/genymotion-error-at-start-unable-to-load-virtualbox?rq=1)

[Unable to load virtualbox engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629013/genymotion-unable-to-load-virtualbox-engine-on-mavericks-vbox-is-setup-corr)